# Having trouble referencing to a certain element on page with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having a terribly hard time referencing to a certain "next page" button on a website that I am trying to scrape links from [https://www.sreality.cz/adresar?strana=2]. If you scroll down you can see a red right arrow button that you can click to go to the next page and so the website load new dynamic content. Every approach seems to report the same exact error and I don't know how am I supposed to point to the element without running into it.

This is the code that I currently have :

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver_path = "/home/user/Dokumenty/iCloud/RealityScraper/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
print("WebDriver Successfully Initialized")
driver.get("https://www.sreality.cz/adresar?strana=2")
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h2.title a")
nextPage = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.paging-item a.btn-paging-pn.icof.icon-arr-right.paging-next")

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
    nextPage.click()
```

The "nextPage" variable is holding a supposed value to be clicked on once the "links" variable search finishes scraping all the links from the company titles. However when I run this code I get an error :

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

I have been searching for various fixes online but none of them seemed to resolve the issue. I think that the issue at this point is not caused by the element not loading quickly enough but rather Selenium having trouble finding the element because of wrong reference.

Because of this I have tried using XPath to accurately point to the actual element and so I changed the "nextPage" variable to :

```
nextPage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[12]/a""")
```

Which returns exactly the same error as stated above. I have been trying to find a solution to this for hours now and I can't understand where the issue lies. I would be grateful if anyone could explain to me what am I doing wrong. Thanks to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all the ng-href tags from every page. Or you could look into their api.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
driver.get("https://www.sreality.cz/adresar?strana=2")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
while True:
    try:
        links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.title > a")))
        #print(len(links))
        for link in links:
            print(link.get_attribute("ng-href"))
        nextPage = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn-paging-pn.icof.icon-arr-right.paging-next")))
        nextPage.click()
        time.sleep(10)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

Comment: After some small modifications from my side this fixed it! My issue probably was that I was stupidly trying to run everything in one loop! Thanks for showing me this now I understand how can this be done better.

Answer (score 0):

First of all never use the absolute `xpath` it will breakdown easily, Use the relative `xpath`.

Secondly, i think the error you are getting is because after clicking "Next" button for the first time it loads a new page. Which has a different DOM structure and that's why you are not able to find that element.

You can try searching for the element after every new page load (after clicking "Next" button everytime.)

```
// imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

// initialize
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
action = ActionChains(driver)


// Try to use the below code and see if it works.
Next_btn = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//li[@class="paging-item"])[2]')))
action.move_to_element(Next_btn).click().perform()
```